# Stuck at parse coordinates with button

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm working with the code of the first answer from: [Phonegap with Compass and GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476515/phonegap-with-compass-and-gps-coordinates/13780468#13780468)

I try to make that don't need to put all time the lat and lon.

For that I'm making a button that get current position, and send to the program to work. But here is where I don't know how to continue, I tryed dozen of times and I'm stuck because I don't know a lot of javascript/jquery.

Any can help me how I need to make the button and send the coordinates to the program?

Here is my version of the program:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Compass test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="jquery-1.7.1.min.js">//</script> <!--http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="latlon.js">//</script> <!-- based on http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html -->


    <style type="text/css">
        #error, #results{
            display: none;
        }

        #arrow{
            position: absolute;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background: 50% 50% no-repeat; 
            background-size: 30px 30px;
            background-image: url('arrow.png');
            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            margin: 30px 0 0 -15px;
        }

        #results .text{
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var destinationPosition;
        var destinationBearing;

        var positionTimerId;
        var currentPosition;
        var prevPosition;
        var prevPositionError;      

        var compassTimerId;
        var currentHeading;
        var prevHeading;
        var prevCompassErrorCode;

        $(document).on("deviceready", function() {
            minPositionAccuracy = 50; // Minimum accuracy in metres to accept as a reliable position
            minUpdateDistance = 1; // Minimum number of metres to move before updating distance to destination

            $targetLat = $('#target-lat');
            $targetLon = $('#target-lon');
            $error = $('#error');           
            $results = $('#results');
            $distance = $('#distance');
            $bearing = $('#bearing');
            $heading = $('#heading');
            $difference = $('#difference');
            $arrow = $('#arrow');

            document.getElementById('#target-lat').value('48');
            document.getElementById('#target-lon').value('-1');

            watchPosition();            
            watchCompass();



            // Set destination
            $targetLat.change(updateDestination);
            $targetLon.change(updateDestination);
            updateDestination();

        });

        function watchPosition(){
            if(positionTimerId) navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(positionTimerId); 
            positionTimerId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onPositionUpdate, onPositionError, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 1000,
                maxiumumAge: 0
            });
        }

        function watchCompass(){
            if(compassTimerId) navigator.compass.clearWatch(compassTimerId);
            compassTimerId = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onCompassUpdate, onCompassError, {
                frequency: 100 // Update interval in ms
            });
        }

        function onPositionUpdate(position){
            if(position.coords.accuracy > minPositionAccuracy) return;

            prevPosition = currentPosition;
            currentPosition = new LatLon(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            if(prevPosition && prevPosition.distanceTo(currentPosition)*1000 < minUpdateDistance) return;

            updatePositions();
        }

        function onPositionError(error){
            watchPosition();

            if(prevPositionError && prevPositionError.code == error.code && prevPositionError.message == error.message) return; 

            $error.html("Error while retrieving current position. <br/>Error code: " + error.code + "<br/>Message: " + error.message);

            if(!$error.is(":visible")){
                $error.show();
                $results.hide();
            }

            prevPositionError = {
                code: error.code,
                message: error.message
            };
        }

        function onCompassUpdate(heading){
            prevHeading = currentHeading;
            currentHeading = heading.trueHeading >= 0 ? Math.round(heading.trueHeading) : Math.round(heading.magneticHeading);

            if(currentHeading == prevHeading) return;

            updateHeading();
        }

        function onCompassError(error){
            watchCompass();

            if(prevCompassErrorCode && prevCompassErrorCode == error.code) return; 

            var errorType;
            switch(error.code){
                case 1:
                    errorType = "Compass not supported";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    errorType = "Compass internal error";
                    break;
                default:
                    errorType = "Unknown compass error";
            }

            $error.html("Error while retrieving compass heading: "+errorType);

            if(!$error.is(":visible")){
                $error.show();
                $results.hide();
            }

            prevCompassErrorCode = error.code;
        }

        function updateDestination(){
            destinationPosition = new LatLon($targetLat.val(), $targetLon.val());
            updatePositions();
        }       


        function updatePositions(){
            if(!currentPosition) return;

            if(!$results.is(":visible")){
                $results.show();
                $error.hide();
            }

            destinationBearing = Math.round(currentPosition.bearingTo(destinationPosition)); 

            $distance.html(Math.round(currentPosition.distanceTo(destinationPosition)*1000));           
            $bearing.html(destinationBearing);

            updateDifference(); 
        }

        function updateHeading(){
            $heading.html(currentHeading);
            updateDifference();
        }

        function updateDifference(){
            var diff = destinationBearing - currentHeading;
            $difference.html(diff);         
            $arrow.css("-webkit-transform", "rotate("+diff+"deg)");         
        }

        function locate(){
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var location_timeout = setTimeout("geolocFail()", 10000);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        clearTimeout(location_timeout);
        locationSuccess(position);
    }, function(error) {
        clearTimeout(location_timeout);
        geolocFail();

    });
    }else{
             showError("Your browser doesn't support geolocation!");
         }
    }

function locationSuccess(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    $('input[id=target-lat]').val(lat);
    $('input[id=target-lon]').val(lon);

    $targetLat.html(lat);
    $targetLon.html(lon);

    $targetLat.change(updateDestination);
    $targetLon.change(updateDestination);
    updateDestination();
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="results">
        <div id="arrow"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Distance to destination: <span id="distance"></span> metres</p>
            <p>Bearing to destination: <span id="bearing"></span> degrees</p>
            <p>Current heading: <span id="heading"></span> degrees</p>      
            <p>Difference in heading and bearing: <span id="difference"></span> degrees</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p id="error"></p>

    <h2>Destination</h2>
    <div>
<p>Current latitude: <span id="target-lat"></span> </p>  
    </div>
    <div>
<p>Current longitude: <span id="target-lon"></span> </p>  
    </div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="locate()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But don't work, all time in results says that the distance is NaN and the arrow don't move.

Else how I can make that saves the position if I close the app?

Sorry and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you added

```
http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation
```

to your config.xml?

Comment: Yes I added    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
              <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>